# How does reduce work in this scenario?

Tags: javascript

I was looking into pipe functions and I came across this reduce function which takes the _pipe function as the parameter. The _pipe function has two params a,b and then returns another function.

**How does reduce work here?**

```
add3 = x => x + 3;
add5 = x => x + 5;
const _pipe = (a, b) => (arg) => b(a(arg))
const pipe = (...ops) => ops.reduce(_pipe)
const add = pipe(add3, add5)
add(10)
```

**output**
    18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at pipe function definition:

```
const pipe = (...ops) => ops.reduce(_pipe)
```

It receives array of functions called ops (this is called [rest params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)).
Then we call reduce for ops array. Reducer function has 2 params: accumulator and current value.

Here is our _pipe written with human readable variables:

```
const _pipe = (accumulator, currentValue) => (arg) => currentValue(accumulator(arg));
```

So the result of _pipe will be curried functions from ops array.

If it's [add3, add5] then result will be (arg) => add3(add5(arg))

If it's [add3, add5, add2] then result is: (arg) => add2(accumulator(arg)) where accumulator is (arg) => add3(add5(arg)).

You simply compose all functions from array using reduce. Then pass initial value which is 10.

It's like: add3(add5(10)) = 18

Answer (score 0):

the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function is equivalent to

```js
add3 = x => x + 3;
add5 = x => x + 5;

const _pipe = (a, b) => (arg) => b(a(arg))

const pipe = (...ops) => {
  // create a base function
  let sum = x => x;
  
  // for every operation
  for (let op of ops) {
    // call _pipe with sum and it
    // equivalent to sum = x => sum(op(x))
    sum = _pipe(sum, op)
  }
  
  // return the resulting function
  return x => sum(x)
}

const add = pipe(add3, add5)

console.log(add(10))
```